# SSL for NodeJs and Networks LAN Intranet

Tags: node.js, ssl, browser, lan, intranet

```
let express = require( 'express' );
let app = express();
let server = require( 'http' ).Server( app );
let io = require( 'socket.io' )( server );
let stream = require( './ws/stream' );
let path = require( 'path' );
let favicon = require( 'serve-favicon' );
app.use( '/assets', express.static( path.join( __dirname, 'assets' ) ) );
app.get( '/', ( req, res ) => {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/index.html' );
} );
io.of( '/stream' ).on( 'connection', stream );
server.listen( 3000 );
```

above here is my node js code.
I tried creating ssl certificate through powershell and on my self created domain for LAN i even put certificate in root trusted dir.
when i type in my ip or domain in browser it does not show secure to my website.